# Getting transaction history via Ethers.js

Tags: ether, metamask, ethereumjs, binance

So I am new to blockchain development and I am trying to build a wallet just like the Metamask. I am struggling with displaying the recieved transactions. How dose one gets the recieved transaction history, and is there a way to get notified to when you recieve a token.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you can get the transaction history:

```
let address = "0x1DF2727Ff34d2BD09ACd3aF576a6dC20De1xxxxx";
let etherscanProvider = new ethers.providers.EtherscanProvider();

etherscanProvider.getHistory(address).then((history) => {
    history.forEach((tx) => {
        console.log(tx);
    })
});
```

Note that this only works with `ethers.providers.EtherscanProvider`. Ethers.js's InfuraProvider does not have the getHistory function.

Answer (score 0):

With ethers you can call for transactions only when using EtherscanProvider as mentioned by Leigh, other providers don't support the history retrieval.
Note that if you need internal transactions history the ethers.providers.EtherscanProvider.getHistory doesn't provide it at all.

So you can call for transactions history manually using the HTTP API endpoint provided by etherscan:
https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-internal-transactions-by-address

And for internal transactions you need to call this endpoint:
https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-internal-transactions-by-address